# Assigning colors randomly to the table cells

Tags: javascript

```
var colors = ['#129793', '#000000', '#FF6600', '#FFCC00', '#00FF00', '#663399', '#34DDDD', '#FF0080', '#028482', '#3399FF', 'magneta', 'crimson', 'fuschia', 'yellow orange', '#5F021F', '#333399', '#FF1A00', '#841F27', '#990000'];

function grid(rows, cols) {
    var size = rows;
    var opacity;

    if (size >= 10)
        opacity = 0.9;
    else
        opacity = size / 10;

    $('td').css("background", colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);

    var table = "<table id = \"myTable\">";
    var size = (1 / rows * 525) + "px";

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        table += "<tr>";

        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            //var ID = i+','+j;
            var ID = 'td_' + i + '_' + j;
            var ID2 = randomFunction(rows, cols);
            //table += "<td id = \"ID\" >"+"</td>";
            table += '<td id = "' + ID + '">&nbsp;</td>';
        }

        table += "</tr>";
    }

    table += "</table>";

    $("#container").empty().append(table);
    $('td').css("background", colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);

    document.getElementById(ID2).style.opacity = opacity;
    document.getElementById(ID2).addEventListener("click", function () {
        grid(parseInt(rows) + 1, parseInt(cols) + 1);
    });
}
```

This is the code written for assigning colors to the table cells generated randomly for kuku kube game. Its working fine, but sometimes color is not being assigned to the cell by which I cannot go to next level. I need to refresh the page to play again. Can I get solution for this?

Comment: repeating.... $('td').css("background", c......

Comment: I tried by removing that...it doesnt work @yjs

Comment: or you can try $("td".each(func.....and add randome colors after table is created.

Comment: I am beginner please  give explanation in detail

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(function() {

var colors = ['#129793', '#000000', '#FF6600', '#FFCC00', '#00FF00', '#663399', '#34DDDD', '#FF0080', '#028482', '#3399FF', 'magneta', 'crimson', 'fuschia', 'yellow orange', '#5F021F', '#333399', '#FF1A00', '#841F27', '#990000'];

function grid(rows, cols) {
    var size = rows;
    var opacity;

    if (size >= 10)
        opacity = 0.9;
    else
        opacity = size / 10;

    var table = "<table id = \"myTable\" style='border:1px solid #ccc;'>";
    var size = (1 / rows * 525) + "px";

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        table += "<tr>";

        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            //var ID = i+','+j;
            var ID = 'td_' + i + '_' + j;
            //var ID2 = randomFunction(rows, cols);
            //table += "<td id = \"ID\" >"+"</td>";
            table += '<td id = "' + ID + '">&nbsp;</td>';
        }

        table += "</tr>";
    }

    table += "</table>";

    jQuery("#container").empty().append(table);
    jQuery('td').each(function() {jQuery(this).css("background", colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]); });

    document.getElementById(ID).style.opacity = opacity;
    document.getElementById(ID).addEventListener("click", function () {
        grid(parseInt(rows) + 1, parseInt(cols) + 1);
    });
}

grid(14,4);
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```